# Process was aborted abnormally but has no core dump file.

Tags: linux, coredump

Result of command "ulimit -c" is unlimited, and machine can generate coredump files for any other processes. Only one process can't generate coredump file when it was aborted. I doubt OS kill it because of memory, but I am not sure. Is there any other reason that can explain it? Wait for your kindly answer.

Comment: What do you mean by or how do you know _it was aborted_? (SIGABRT is different from the OOM killer's SIGKILL.) Did you look at `syslog`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it with -g3 flag and then run.

Comment: I compiled it with flag -g2, and has no effect.